SwiftUI and NavigationLink - optional var in destination view is not initialising
I use in iOS app NavigationLink in NavigationView (for supporting iOS 15). NavigationView contains list of some items. I would like to use the same view for adding new items and editing exist (after click on NavigationLink). So I need to pass "PersonEntity" to PersonAddOrEditView. This view has 2 init (one with empty params for "add form" and the second one with "PersonEntity" parameter for initialising form fields).
The problem is that I can't initialise optional fields (vars). They are staying nil and picker (or selectable list in comment) always "choosing" first value(1). It works if I make @State var age: Int? non-optional.
Also if I make @State var name: String as Optional than TextField will be empty (not initialised) for "edit" form.
Thanks in advance for your advices.
UPD
Initialisation of @State var age: Int? does not work for "add" and "edit" views. The same situation will be for "name" if I change @State var name: String to @State var name: String?.
import SwiftUI

struct NavigationLinkForm: View {
    var persons: [PersonEntity] = [
        PersonEntity(name: "Person 1", age: 20),
        PersonEntity(name: "Person 2", age: 25),
        PersonEntity(name: "Person 3", age: 30),
    ]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Add new person") {
                    PersonAddOrEditView()
                }
                List {
                    ForEach(persons, id: \.self) { person in
                        NavigationLink(person.name) {
                            PersonAddOrEditView(personEntity: person)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PersonEntity: Hashable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int?
}

struct PersonAddOrEditView: View {
    
    let personEntity: PersonEntity?
    
    @State var name: String
    @State var age: Int?
    
    private var isNew: Bool {
        personEntity == nil
    }

    init(personEntity: PersonEntity) {
        self.personEntity = personEntity
        self.name = personEntity.name
        self.age = personEntity.age
    }
    
    init() {
        self.personEntity = nil
        self.name = ""
        self.age = 10
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                
                Picker("Age", selection: $age) {
                    ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { ageItem in
                        Text("\(ageItem)")
                            .tag(ageItem)
                            .id(ageItem)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.menu)
                
//                NavigationLink("\(age ?? 0)") {
//                    List(selection: $age) {
//                        ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { ageItem in
//                            Text("\(ageItem)")
//                                .tag(ageItem)
//                                .id(ageItem)
//                        }
//                    }
//                }
            }
            if isNew {
                Button("Add") { }
            } else {
                Button("Update") { }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    NavigationLinkForm()
}


How about passing a new created PersonEntity with a sample name for example "New Person" or with your default data in the init method?

Assigning (initialisation) values to optional var "age" (or name) don't work in both init methods. It works just if var is not optional.

There are several ways. One of them is if you don't use the properties of PersonEntity anyway declare the view property age non-optional and set the struct property to nil if 0 is selected. Or create a custom Binding which can handle the nil case.

@vadian In my project I use selectable List instead of Picker which requires Optional variable for "selection". About "custom Binding" - so are these some restrictions of swiftUI for using optional vars in destination view for NavigationLink?

Looks like it is problem with initialisation of @State var in init. And looks like it's not possible to initialise Optional @State var.. link [/link]

I created ViewModel and use in a View @Pablished vars of ViewModel instead of own @State vars. Picker still does not initialise. But selectable List is initialising by "age" value and works correct.
So I still can't figure out how does initialisation of Optional @Published and @State variables work in SwiftUI?..
import SwiftUI

struct NavigationLinkForm: View {
    var persons: [PersonEntity] = [
        PersonEntity(name: "Person 1", age: 20),
        PersonEntity(name: "Person 2", age: 25),
        PersonEntity(name: "Person 3", age: 30),
    ]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Add new person") {
                    PersonAddOrEditView(vm: PersonAddOrEditViewModel())
                }
                List {
                    ForEach(persons, id: \.self) { person in
                        NavigationLink(person.name) {
//                            PersonAddOrEditView(personEntity: person)
                            PersonAddOrEditView(vm: PersonAddOrEditViewModel(personEntity: person))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PersonEntity: Hashable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int?
}

class PersonAddOrEditViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let personEntity: PersonEntity?
    
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var age: Int?
    
    var isNew: Bool {
        personEntity == nil
    }
    
    init(personEntity: PersonEntity) {
        self.personEntity = personEntity
        self.name = personEntity.name
        self.age = personEntity.age ?? 99
    }
    
    init() {
        self.personEntity = nil
        self.name = ""
        self.age = 10
    }
}

struct PersonAddOrEditView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm: PersonAddOrEditViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                TextField("Name", text: $vm.name)
                
                // Picker's selection doesn't initialized
                Picker("Age", selection: $vm.age) {
                    ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { ageItem in
                        Text("\(ageItem)")
                            .tag(ageItem)
                            .id(ageItem)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.menu)
                
                // Selectable list's selection is works
                NavigationLink("\(vm.age ?? 0)") {
                    List(selection: $vm.age) {
                        ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { ageItem in
                            Text("\(ageItem)")
                                .tag(ageItem)
                                .id(ageItem)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if vm.isNew {
                Button("Add") { }
            } else {
                Button("Update") { }
            }
        }
    }
}

